# Creación de una estructura organizacional usando CSS y jquery.orgchart.js

Tags: jquery, sql-server, php8, orgchart

Estaba siguiendo algunos ejemplos https://github.com/phpdev-expert/Org-chart es interesante ver lo que se puede lograr con  jquery.orgchart.js y css. Dado que el ejemplo mencionado funciona con un bucle for en javascript que ordena segun la id y los alias de una tabla ¿Cómo se puede lograr que se genere arrays en el for en javascript?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he unido dos consultas  en un solo array lo que quiero lograr ahora es poder cargar el resultado en un array pero en javascript pero no se como hacerlo, he intentado con este codigo de esta manera

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.orgchart.css" />
    <script src="jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            var members;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'load.php',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    members = $.parseJSON(data)
                }
            })

            //memberId,parentId,otherInfo
            for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
              
                var member = members[i];
               let arrayName = [memberId, parentId, OtherInfo];
 $data = array(

        'Principal' => array(
            "codigo" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['parentId']),
            'Secundario' => array(
                "miembro" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['memberId']),
                "info" => utf8_encode($datos[$i]['otherInfo']),
            ),
        ),
    );
                if (i == 0) {
                    $("#mainContainer").append("<li id=" + 
            member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
                } else {

                    if ($('#pr_' + member.parentId).length <= 0) {
                        $('#' + member.parentId).append("<ul id='pr_" + member.parentId + "'><li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li></ul>")
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#pr_' + member.parentId).append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
                    }

                }
            }


            $("#mainContainer").orgChart({ container: $("#main"), interactive: true, fade: true, speed: 'slow' });

        }); 
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="display: none">


        <ul id="mainContainer" class="clearfix"></ul>

    </div>
    <div id="main">

    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

por ejemplo la tabla usuarios se ordena a partir de iduser y parent que es la columna que sirve para ordenar segun el rango lo que quiero lograr es que a partir de la id del usuario tabien se pueda crear otro nivel en el organigrama la de pais según una subconsulta en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el archivo de consulta tengo mi codigo de esta forma he logrado unir las dos consultas mediante **array_merge** ahora lo que quiero lograr es que se genere un array en el script que genera el org-chart para asi mediante el array crear las dependencias de padre e hijo
*¿Algún gurú que pueda ayudar?*

```html
<?php

$serverName = "server";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "tree", "UID" => "SA", "PWD" => "1234", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


$sql = "select iduser as memberId, parent as parentId  ,users as otherInfo from users";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$datos = [];
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos[] = $row;
}

if (isset($row)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

$sql1 = "select iduser as  parentId  ,nompais as otherInfo from pais";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);

$datos1 = [];
while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos1[] = $row1;
}

if (isset($row1)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json1 = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt1);


$resultado = array_merge($datos,$datos1);
echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Comment: Tu archivo PHP imprime 2 JSON, por lo cual no deberia funcionar. Asegurate de que el archivo devuela 1 JSON. Luego, en base a la estructura del mismo vas a necesitar acomodar el Javascript. Actualmente no se corresponden

Comment: imprimi los resultados en una sola variable  $resultado=array_merge($datos,$datos1);
echo json_encode($resultado);  ¿cómo puedo crear un array dentro del script?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar los nuevos cambios?